# can't read all file lines in bash pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, pipeline

I searched and couldn't find anything, maybe I can't understand the problem properly.
I have a bash function who read files in current dir and sub dir's, I'm trying to arrange the text and analyze the data but somehow I'm losing lines if I'm using pipeline.
the code:

```
function recursiveFindReq {
    for file in *.request; do
        if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
          echo handling "$file"
          echo ---------------with pipe-----------------------
          cat "$file" | while read -a line; do  
            if (( ${#line} > 1 )); then
                echo ${line[*]}
            fi
          done
          echo ----------------without pipe----------------------
          cat "$file"
          echo
          echo num of lines: `cat "$file" | wc -l`
          echo --------------------------------------
        fi
    done

    for dir in ./*; do
        if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
            echo cd to $dir
            cd "$dir"
            recursiveFindReq "$1"
            cd ..
        fi
    done
}
```

the output is:
[losing lines even when they meet requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzdkU.png)

I marked with 2 red arrows the place I'm losing info

Comment: Your code is missing at least one `done` and one `fi`.

Comment: You also have useless uses of `cat`; both calls could be replaced with input redirection. Please run your code through shellcheck.net.

Comment: That said, each text file appears to be a DOS text file whose last "line" isn't terminated by a line feed, which means neither `read` nor `wc` recognize it as a line as such.

Comment: @chepner I'm doing it right now, thanks (fi and done added)

Comment: @Dennis Vash maybe you could help